# How would the vacuum look like if no mass/energy is present in it?

Tags: vacuum, cosmological-inflation

The observable universe is thought to inflate faster and faster towards infinity. The energy will be diluted to zero in the far future.

The influence of attractive gravity is getting smaller and smaller because matter-energy decreases.

Does this mean that it's a property of the vacuum, if matter-energy is absent, that it inflates like mad?

Answer (score 0):

That would not be the case, the expansion of the universe is not related to it’s vacuum like property. It is effected by the energy behind the big bang and density. The accelerating expansion tells us that the energy from the big bang greatly out ways the gravitational pull of its contents. However this didn’t have to be the case, there are many theoretical scenarios in which the universe slows down and eventually accelerates the opposite direction. Observational evidence tells us we’re likely not in this category though.

Comment: But what causes expansion? The less the contribution of matter-energy, the harder the vacuum expands. So its a property of quantum vacuum.

Comment: @Felicia I agree that the vacuum expands faster without matter present. But that doesn’t necessarily mean that  it’s a property of a quantum vacuum. For example, Dark matter/energy are just as viable in describing universal expansion. If it were possible to create an absolute vacuum in some container, we couldn’t guarantee it would expand.

Comment: But a classical Einstein vacuum doesn't expand.  It's a property of a vacuum with quantum bubbling.

Comment: By a piece of absolute vacuum in a container (nice image!), you mean a piece of vacuum with the container and the rest of the universe missing?